# Microsoft.NET Framework - Unhandled DLL Exception Occured

Tags: vb.net

I just **published** a VB Program, which, on executing indicates this error:

[image]

I click on continue and **the application works fine but some features are removed**. The problem is not limited to this, but, if I click Quit, the error still comes.

*How to overcome this problem?*

Comment: its a problem with your code. specifically the other assemblies you may have deployed are not the latest one which can cause this to happen from the error message. be sure that the DLL is the same one you are deploying as you are developing on. Did you even look @ the stacktrace?

Comment: Do I need to fix the DLL file - hppatusg01? If so, how to fix it?

Comment: I cannot tell you how to fix it since I did not write the code. you need to start debugging and looking through the stacktrace and make sure what you deploy is all the same and not just a single DLL. you may have changed several assemblies but only deployed the one or just deployed several but forgot to deploy one of the changed assemblies

Comment: It is a Hewlett Packard support DLL, usually something to do with a printer.  Reinstall the driver for the device.  Contact Hewlett Packard if you need support.

Comment: You're right! I have a Hewlett Packard printer and I have print feature too in my application!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it myself! Thanks for helping!

1) Download **DLL Files fixer**.

2) Search the name of DLL file (hppatusg01.dll).

3) Fix / **Re-install the DLL file**.

4) Right click the application.

5) Click **Open with and select the downloaded dll file**.

It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If you published it via click once then you will have to include that DLL in your click once assembly by going to Project > Publish > Application files and make sure it is included. If the DLL is a helper file for an API you are using just add it to the root of your project so it gets published in the root of your project.

Comment: What does click once mean?

Comment: It probably means you are not using it. How did you "publish" your application.

Comment: Build -> Publish '..' -> Set the location -> Next -> Published to CD-DVD too. Finished. Then installed the setup and pinned it to the start menu! That's all!

Comment: Ok. Are you using any special controls which require a helper dll or did you make "hppatusg01.dll"?